# PHP memory_get_peak_usage and ini_set('memory_limit', '-1')

Tags: php, memory-management, memory-limit

I recently ran into memory allocation problems, so I started experimenting with the `ini_set('memory_limit', value);` directive where I tried to enter values incrementaly. Now, searching through the web (and SO) I found out that I can put `-1` as the `value`. So, I did and now the script runs fully to the end without breaking (before I used to get the memory allocation error).

What I don't understand, however, is that given these two lines at the end of the script's file:

```
$mem = memory_get_peak_usage(true);         
echo "Peak mem. usage: <b>" . round($mem / 1024 / 10124, 2) . "</b> MB";
```

produce around **10.8MB** and when I look into the `/var/log/messages` I can see this line:

```
Nov 21 13:52:26 mail suhosin[1153]: ALERT-SIMULATION - script tried to increase  
memory_limit to 4294967295 bytes which is above the allowed value (attacker  
'xx.xxx.xxx.xxx', file '/var/www/html/file.php', line 5)
```

which means the script tried to alocate **4096MB**!

How can this be? And also, what interest me the most is why didn't the script execution stop in this case? Is it because of the `ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');`? I mean, I did read that putting `-1` as the `value` is not recomended and I know where the problem lies in the script (reading too big amount of data at once in the memory), and I will go and fix it with sequential reading, but I'm just baffled about these data differences, so I would be gratefull if someone can shed some light on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because the suhosin patch uses its own "hard" maximum memory limit, [`suhosin.memory_limit`](http://www.hardened-php.net/suhosin/configuration.html#suhosin.memory_limit).

From the configuration reference:

> Suhosin [...] disallows setting the `memory_limit` to a value **greater than the one the script started with**, when this option is left at 0.

In other words, if you change the `memory_limit` so that it is bigger than suhosin's upper limit then it will simply assume that you are an "attacker" trying to do something suspicious.

Answer (score 0):

think you used 10MB but by putting `-1` as `value` you allowed your script to use maxmimum memory available, say `4GB`.

Answer (score 0):

Using `ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');` will not set a limit for the scripts - of course it'll still be restricted to hardware, but from the manual;

> Note that to have no memory limit, set this directive to -1

**What interest me the most is why didn't the script execution stop in this case?**

The script didn't stop execution because it didn't reach the maximum memory limit, as it's set to `-1`.

Answer (score 0):

memory_get_peak_usage — Returns the peak of memory allocated by PHP.

memory_limit - increase maximum memory allocation

```
<?php 
if(ini_set('memory_limit', '-1'))
{
    echo "memory_limit set to -1B";
}
else
{
    echo "ini_set() failed!"
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

As describe here : http://www.hardened-php.net/suhosin/configuration.html#suhosin.memory_limit

Suhosin will not let you *set a value greater than the one the script started with*.

If you set the **suhosin.memory_limit** to **4096** then you'll be able to increase your memory usage without getting this alert

My guess is the script didn't try to allocate **4096MB** but its a wrong alert of shuosin showing the maximum addressable memory limit of a **32 bit system** on which the php server is running that is **2^32**

Hope this answers your doubts

Answer (score 0):

```
$mem / 1024 / 10124
```

should be

```
$mem / 1024 / 1024
```

So we're talking about a 100 MB peak.

Then `4,294,967,295 = 4 GB`. I guess that's all you have (i.e. the `-1`).

This means these output messages have nothing to do with each other. If you want the warning to disappear, [set the Suhosin memory limit](http://www.hardened-php.net/suhosin/configuration.html#suhosin.memory_limit) higher than the PHP memory limit or disable Suhosin.

Suhosin has a [simulation mode](http://www.hardened-php.net/suhosin/configuration.html#suhosin.simulation) which seems to be `ON`. If this is turned `OFF`, the ALERT should stop the script.